# Compiling mvapich2-2.1 with PGI

Tags: mpi, pgi, mvapich2

I am currently trying to compile mvapich2-2.1 using pgcc 15.10 on a CentOS 6 machine.  I run

```
export F90=; export CPP=cpp; ./configure --prefix=/home/user/local/mvapich2-2.1/pgi15
make
```

and it fails with (excluding much of the diagnostic output)

```
.
.
.
PGC/x86-64 Linux 15.10-0: compilation completed with warnings
  CC       adio/common/ad_iwrite_fake.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_open.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_opencoll.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_opencoll_failsafe.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_opencoll_scalable.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_prealloc.lo
  CC       adio/common/ad_read.lo
PGC-W-0114-More than one type specified (/gpfs0/export/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.10/include-gcc44/sys/types.h: 230)
PGC-W-0143-Useless typedef declaration (no declarators present) (/gpfs0/export/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.10/include-gcc44/sys/types.h: 230)
PGC/x86-64 Linux 15.10-0: compilation completed with warnings
  CC       adio/common/ad_read_coll.lo
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:1510: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:1547: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2003: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2272: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2324: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2376: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2435: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2621: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2895: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2932: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:2986: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
/tmp/pgccZZGhzd4sbsRT.s:3038: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpxor'
make[3]: *** [adio/common/ad_read_coll.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/gpfs0/home/user/local/src/mvapich2-2.1/src/mpi/romio'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/gpfs0/home/user/local/src/mvapich2-2.1/src/mpi/romio'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/gpfs0/home/user/local/src/mvapich2-2.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the solution to this problem?  I have no experience using the assembler, so any hints / advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: check the following page from PGI forum - it could be relevant. Please provide additional information on your operating system which can be relevant. http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=4502&view=next&sid=57ed7fc850f23a24014889d41e1058f7

Answer (score 1):

I got it to install by using the following :

```
F90=; CPP=cpp; CFLAGS="-tp penryn-64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64" ./configure --prefix=/home/user/local/mvapich2-2.1/pgi15
make
make install
```

I also tried updating binutils to 2.24 and I was able to install it that way also.